# pass the data from uitableview to other uiview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, segue

I'm new in swift and IOS, i have some problem to pass the dictionary data to other uiview, anyone can help me to fix it?

LessonsTableViewController:

```
var mylessons = [
    ["title":"Posture", "subtitle":"Set up your body", "bgimage":"1", "lesimage":"l1"],
    ["title":"Breathing", "subtitle":"Breathing deeply", "bgimage":"2", "lesimage":"l2"],
    ["title":"Breathing", "subtitle":"Breathing Exercise", "bgimage":"3", "lesimage":"l3"],
    ["title":"Health", "subtitle":"Do’s & Don’ts", "bgimage":"4", "lesimage":"l4"]
]
```

and

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! LessonsTableViewCell

    let lessonsObject = mylessons[indexPath.row]

    cell.backgroundImageView.image = UIImage(named: lessonsObject["bgimage"]!)
    cell.titleLabel.text = lessonsObject["title"]
    cell.subtitleLabal.text = lessonsObject["subtitle"]

    return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "LessonSegue", sender: mylessons[indexPath.row])
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?){
    let lessegue = segue.destination as! LessonDetailsViewController
    lessegue.SelectedLessons = mylessons
}
```

LessonDetailsViewController:

```
    @IBOutlet weak var LTitle: UILabel!

var SelectedLessons = [Dictionary<String, String>()]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    LTitle.text = SelectedLessons["title"]
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

Finally, it has an error "Cannot subscript a value of type '[Dictionary]' with an index of type 'String'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First your **SelectedLessons** is wrong type. You need use something like tis

```
var SelectedLessons:Dictionary<String, String>?
```

And you need past correct object.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?){
    let lessegue = segue.destination as! LessonDetailsViewController
    lessegue.SelectedLessons = sender as? Dictionary<String,String>
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it's work for my application now. In addition,
    LTitle.text = SelectedLessons["title"] need to change LTitle.text = SelectedLessons?["title"]

Answer (score 0):

You should declare

```
var SelectedLessons = [String, String]()
```

Your current declaration is an array of dictionaries

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of problems.

First is a coding style issue. Variable names should start with a lower-case letter, so `SelectedLessons` should be `selectedLessons`.

Second, you likely want to pass the user-selected lesson to the destination, not the entire array.

Your array `mylessons` is an array of dictionaries: (Type `[[String:String]]`)

You should probably name the variable in `LessonDetailsViewController` `selectedLesson` (singular, starting with a lower-case letter) and make it type `[String: String]` (a single lesson.)

Then your prepareForSegue might look like this:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?){
    guard  
      let lessegue = segue.destination as? LessonDetailsViewController,
      let selectedRow = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row else {
        print("Error. No row selected. Exiting."
        fatalError()
      }
    lessegue.selectedLesson = myLessons[selectedRow]
}
```

(The code above should have better error handling for the case where there's not a selected row, but it should give you the idea.)

### EDIT:

By the way, it's not a good idea to write your `prepare(for:)` method as if you will only ever segue to a single view controller of a single type. It's very common to go back and expand an app to add additional segues, and if you do that, the code above will crash. Better to use a switch statement:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?){
    switch segue.destination {
      case let lessegue as LessonDetailsViewController:
        guard  
        let selectedRow = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row else {
          print("Error. No row selected. Exiting."
          fatalError()
        }
        lessegue.selectedLesson = myLessons[selectedRow]
      default:
        print("Unrecognized segue. Exiting."
        fatalError()
    }
}
```

That syntax creates a switch statement where each case is executed based on the type of the destination view controller, with a built-in cast to the destination type. It's a neat variant of the switch statement that's very useful in `prepare(for:)` functions.